# Change Text Cursor Size in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, caret

I'm making a simple text editor, and I have a JTextPane and changed the spacing to 1.5f. The only problem is that the "Text Cursor" spans all the pixels from the current line to the next one, regardless of font size. Here's an example:

[image: Large Cursor]

Is  there anyway I can make the text cursor size automatically adjust to the text size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here http://java-sl.com/tip_overwrite_mode.html how to change caret shape.

Alternatively yu can override modelToView method to correct returned rectangle's shape (height).

Comment: this works to change the caretWidth, but not the height, i.e:
`text.putClientProperty("caretWidth", 2);`
But this doesn't
`text.putClientProperty("caretHeigth", 2);`

with `text` being my JTextPane

Answer (score 2):

The "text cursor" is normally called "caret" in GUI libraries. Same in swing. You can use the method `setCaret` to change it. To change the appearance, inherit from `javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret` and override method `paint`.

Comment: Okay, now it says "The method paint(Graphics, DefaultCaret) of type Display must override or implement a supertype method" and tells me to delete the override.